# Python get argparse to sum data by group using groupby

Tags: python, argparse

I have a dataset that looks like this, the numbers in `NY`, `LA` and `CHI` columns are the number of times people visited those cities.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Person':['A','B','C','D','E','F'], 
    'NY':[1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0],
    'LA':[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    'CHI':[2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    'Gender':['F','F','F','M','M','NA'],
    'Citizenship':['US','Canada','US','US','Mexico','Canada'],
    'Age':['30s','30s','50s','NA','20s','30s']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I'm summing those up by different groups, defined by `Gender`, `Citizenship` or `Age`. I could do this like below.

```
n_by_gender = df.groupby(['Gender']).sum()
n_by_citizenship = df.groupby(['Citizenship']).sum()
n_by_age = df.groupby(['Age']).sum()
pd.concat([df, n_by_gender, n_by_citizenship, n_by_age])
```

Now I'm trying to write an `argparse` module that can do something similar to this. I wanted to put in two arguments in it, so that people can choose which group they want the data to be summed up by. (For instance, if people type in `python modulename.py -Gender -Age`, it will return what I produced above, except the rows that summed up number of visits by citizenship.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Sum data by group')
parser.add_argument('-g', default = "Gender", type=str)  ### need to add some action here?
parser.add_argument('-c', default = "Citizenship", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.b_string)
print(args.c_string)
```

I've been reading `argparse` documents and what doesn't make sense to me is that every action seems to be added inside the `parser.add_argument()`  using the `action` class? How do I add in the `groupby().sum()` command inside the `parser.add_argument()`, or is this a very wrong understanding of how `argparse` works?

Comment: The purpose of `argparse` is parse the input, to figure out what the user wants.  Frequently the result is a simple string value, or list of strings.  The `action` parameter is basically limited to the documented ones.  That 'action' has nothing to do with the functions that will end up using the values.  Acting on the inputs is the responsibility of your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to retrieve the argument from `argparse` and pass that into the functionality of your data manipulation. If this is so, here's how you would do that:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Sum data by group')
parser.add_argument("groupby1",default="Gender", type=str, help="groupby this column (case sensitive)")
parser.add_argument("groupby2",default="Citizenship", type=str, help="groupby this column (case sensitive)")

# Get your arguments
args = parser.parse_args()
groupby_1 = args.groupby1
groupby_2 = args.groupby2


# If they exist, perform your manipulation
all_agg = []
for g in [groupby1, groupby2]:
  if g:
    # Do it
    df_agg = df.groupby([g]).sum()
    all_agg.append(df_agg)

# This is not the best way to perform this aggregation
# but your question was focused on argparse so I'll skip over this part
df_agg = pd.concat(all_agg)
```

Execution of this file would be done as follows:

```
python3 my_file.py Gender Citizenship
```